# How do I choose couples who are not from the same family?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations

> Question:
>
> How many ways can a $5-$member commission consisting of $6$ couples (sister-brother) be chosen so that there are no couples from the same family in the commission?

I need a detailed explanation  to understand this problem. I know I will use combinations.  But I don't know how.I have difficulty understanding the question.  I really need a solution I can understand.  If I understand this, I can do the others myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of different ways we can pick 5 couples out of the 6 is $6\choose5$. We can choose one of two people from each couple, making $2^5$ different committees from those 5 couples we chose. So, the total number of committees possible is:
$${6\choose 5}2^5=192$$

Comment: The result should be less than $\binom{ 6}{5}$, right?

Comment: I can not understand the method :(

Comment: The result should be more than $6\choose 5$, because $6\choose 5$ represents the number of combinations of families present on the commission. You can choose between 2 people from each of the 5 families, which amounts to $2^5$ possible arrangements.

Comment: Thank you. Why do we multiply $2^5$ not $\binom{5}{2}$ ?

Comment: No problem. We use $2^5$ instead of $5\choose 2$ because each family has 2 choices, and so we multiply $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2=2^5$.

Comment: Thank you..now I can start understand..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is confusingly worded; the commission is a "5-member commission," yet at the same time it is "consisting of $6$ couples"? Also, what does "couples from the same family" mean?

I think what the question is supposed to saying is this:

> There are $6$ pairs of people, each consisting of a brother and sister. How many ways are there to select a $5$-person commission from these $12$ people, so that no two people on the commission are siblings?

If you left out the phrase "no two people on the commission are siblings", the answer would be $\binom{12}5$, but with this restriction, the answer is less. With this interpretation, [doobdood's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3731942/177399) is correct.